# Existence/uniqueness of the solution to some SDE with discontinuous coefficient

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a SDE

$$dX_t = b(t,X_t)dt + f\big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t,\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(\ast)$$

where $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a Brownian motion and

$$f(z):={\bf 1}_{\{z>0\}} +\frac{1}{2}{\bf 1}_{\{z\le 0\}}.$$

Assume $b, a: \mathbb R_+\times\mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ are both bounded and Lipschitz. Can we obtain the existence/uniqueness result for $(\ast)$?

Any answers, remarks or references are appreciated!

PS : I tried to approximate $(\ast)$ by replacing $f$ with

$$f_n(z):=\min\left(\frac{nx^++1}{2},~1\right),$$

where $x^+:=\max(x,0)$. Denote by $(n\ast)$ the corresponding SDE. Then it is not hard to show the existence/uniqueness of the solution, denoted by $X^n$, and further the tightness of $(X^n)_{n\ge 1}$. But I do not know how to the limit verifies $(\ast)$.

Comment: An idea - after using Girsanov to remove the drift term (the transformation may differ for each $n$), we have SDE’s that look like $X^n = \sigma^n (t, X_t)$, with $\sigma$ Lipschitz and bounded away from $0$ uniformly in $n$. If we can get a bound such as that given here - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403604/a-bound-for-the-occupation-time-of-a-diffusion for the time spent near $0$, then we should have some kind of convergence in probability of the transformed SDE of $X^n$ to that of $X$. To deal with the differing measures $Q_n$, we need to show that $Q_n \to Q$ in some suitable sense.

Comment: PS - Is your expression for $f_n$ correct?

Comment: Edit: The expression in the first line should read $dX^n_t = \sigma^n (t, X_t) dW^n_t$.

Comment: @NateRiver Could you please specify the Girsanov's transformation to this case? Note that both drift and volatility depend on $X_t$.

Comment: @NateRiver Yes. $f_n$ is Lipschitz and converges pointwise to $f$

Comment: I believe it should be $\frac{d\mathbb Q^n}{d\mathbb P} = \mathcal E(N_T)$, where $\mathcal E(.)$ denotes the Doleans Dade exponential and $N_T := \int_{0}^T -\frac{b(t, X^n_t)}{f_n(a(t, X^n_t))} dB_t$. For a proof that it works, see Protter’s *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*, pg 137.

Comment: Although I tried working out some of the details for my idea and many complications arose that I wasn’t able to resolve…

Answer (score 2):

I believe we can prove (strong) existence at least. I will take for granted a slightly modified version of the result proven by Mateusz Kwasniski [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403604/a-bound-for-the-occupation-time-of-a-diffusion). Namely,

**Lemma 1:**

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion and $\sigma: [0, T] \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ a Borel function with $C_1 < \sigma < C_2$ for some constants $C_1, C_2 > 0$.

Let $Y$ be the solution to the SDE

$$dY_t = \sigma(t, Y_t) dW_t$$ with $Y_0 = y_0$.

Fix $Y > 0$. Then there exists, for every $\varepsilon, h > 0$, a $\delta_{\varepsilon, h} > 0$ such that, for all $U \subset [0, T] \times \mathbb R$ with $\mu(U) < \delta$,

$$\mathbb P\left(\int_{0}^T \mathbf 1_{U} (s, X_s) ds > h\right) < \varepsilon.$$

Where $\mu$ denotes the (product) Lebesgue measure.

**Proof of main theorem:**

We work over the interval $[0, T]$, and without loss of generality assume for simplicity the initial condition $X_0 = 0$.

Let $X^n$ be the solution to the SDE

$$dX^n_t = b(t,X^n_t)dt + f_n \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t$$

with $X^n_0 = 0$.

Where $f_n (z) := \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \min(nx^+,1)$.

Define, for each $n$, a probability measure $\mathbb Q^n$ by $\frac{d\mathbb Q^n}{d\mathbb P} = \mathcal E(N_T)$, where $\mathcal E(.)$ denotes the Doleans Dade exponential, and $N_T := \int_{0}^T -\frac{b(t, X^n_t)}{f_n(a(t, X^n_t))} dB_t$.

Then by Girsanov's theorem, $\mathbb Q^n$ is equivalent to $\mathbb P$, and under $\mathbb Q^n$, we have that

$$dX^n_t = f_n \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dB^n_t$$

with $B^n_t$ a standard Brownian motion.
Let $\varepsilon, h > 0$ be arbitrary. We note also that $\frac{d\mathbb Q^n}{d\mathbb P}$ are uniformly integrable over $n$, thus there exists some $\eta > 0$ such that $\mathbb P(A) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ whenever $\mathbb Q^n (A) < \eta$ for some $n$.

Choose some $K > 0$ large enough such that for all $n > 0$, $\mathbb P(\sup_t |X^n_t| \leq K) > 1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, which we may do by standard $L^p$ bounds on solutions to SDE with Lipschitz coefficients.

Now, for each $\delta > 0$, we may find some $N_{\delta} > 0$ such that $\mu((a^{-1}((0, \frac{1}{N_{\delta}}))) \cap ([0, T] \times [-K, K])) < \delta$.

Thus, for all $n$, we have $\mathbb Q^n \left(\{\int_{0}^T \mathbf 1_{(0, 1/N)} (a(s, X^n_s))ds > h \} \text{ and } \{\sup_t |X^n_t| < K\}\right)< \eta$ as soon as we set $\delta = \delta_{\eta, h}$ as in Lemma 1, and $N = N_{\delta}$. Consequently, $\mathbb P\left(\int_{0}^T \mathbf 1_{(0, 1/N)} (a(s, X^n_s))ds > h \right)< \varepsilon$. $(*)$

Admitting the ucp convergence of $X^n$ to $X$ as stated in the original post, we now show that the limit $X$ satisfies the SDE given. We compute

$|X_t - \int b(t,X_t) dt - \int f\big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t|$

$\leq |X_t - X^n_t| + |X^n_t - \int b(t,X_t) dt - \int f\big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t|$

$= |X_t - X^n_t| + |\int b(t,X^n_t) dt + \int f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t - \int b(t,X_t) dt - \int f\big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t|$

$\leq |X_t - X^n_t| + |\int b(t,X^n_t) dt - \int b(t,X_t) dt| + |\int f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t - \int f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t| + |\int f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t - \int f\big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t|.$

Since $X$ is the ucp limit of the $X^n$, the first term goes to $0$ in probability uniformly in $t$, while the same goes for the second and fourth terms by the dominated convergence theorem for stochastic integrals.

For the third term, we crucially use $(*)$ to obtain ucp convergence of $\int f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) dW_t$ to $\int f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) dW_t$, noting that $f = f_n$ outside of $(0, \frac{1}{n})$.

Let us show in more detail the claimed convergence for the third and fourth term.

**Third term:**

Let $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$ be arbitrary. We will show that $\mathbb P \big(\mathbf 1_{A_n^c} \int_{[0, T]} f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t > \delta\big)< \varepsilon$ for all large enough $n$.

To this end, fix some $h > 0$ depending on $\varepsilon, \delta$ to be chosen later.

By $(*)$, there exists $N > 0$ such that $\mathbb P\left(\int_{0}^T \mathbf 1_{(0, 1/N)} (a(s, X^n_s))ds > h\right)< \frac{\varepsilon \sqrt \delta}{2T}$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z_+$.

Consequently, denoting by $A_n$ the event $\{\int_{0}^T \mathbf 1_{(0, 1/N)} (a(s, X^n_s))ds > h \}$, for all $n > N$ we have

$\mathbb E \big[\left(\int_{[0, T]} f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t\right)^2\big]$

$= \mathbb E \left[\int_{[0, T]} \left[f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right]$

$= \mathbb E \left [\mathbf 1_{A_n^c}\int_{[0, T]} \left[f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right] + \mathbb E \left[[\mathbf 1_{A_n}\int_{[0, T]} \left[f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right]$

$=  \mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{A_n^c} \int_{t \in S} \left[f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right] + \mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{A_n^c} \int_{t \in S^c} \left[ f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right] + \mathbb E \left[[\mathbf 1_{A_n}\int_{[0, T]} \left[f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right]$

where here $S$ denotes the (random) set of all $t \in [0, T]$ such that $a(s, X^n_t) \in (0, \frac{1}{N})$. Noting now that noting that $f = f_n$ outside of $(0, \frac{1}{N})$, we have that the integral over $S^c$ is zero. Consequently, continuing the manipulation from above we have

$\dots = \mathbb E\left[\ \mathbf 1_{A_n^c} \int_{t \in S} \left[f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right] + \mathbb E \left[[\mathbf 1_{A_n}\int_{[0, T]} \left[f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right]$

$\leq \mathbb E \left[\mathbf 1_{A_n^c} \int_{t \in S} \frac{1}{2}dt\right] + E[\frac{T}{2}\mathbf 1_{A_n}]$

= $\frac{h}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon \delta^2}{2}.$

And thus by the Markov inequality we have

$\mathbb P \big(\left [ \int_{[0, T]} f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t\right]^2 > \delta^2\big) < \frac{\varepsilon \delta^2 + h}{2\delta^2}$.

Setting now $h = \varepsilon \delta^2$, we obtain

$\mathbb P \big(\left[\mathbf \int_{[0, T]} f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t\right]^2 > \delta^2 \big) < \varepsilon$

and thus

$\mathbb P \big(\left|\mathbf \int_{[0, T]} f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t\right| >  \delta\big)< \varepsilon$

as claimed.

**Fourth term:**

Let again $\varepsilon, \delta > 0$ be arbitrary. Fix $h, r > 0$ depending on $\varepsilon, \delta$ to be chosen later.

By the same reasoning as $(*)$, there exists $N > 0$ such that $\mathbb P\left(\int_{0}^T \mathbf 1_{(-1/N, 1/N)} (a(s, X^n_s))ds > h\right) < r$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z_+$. For each $n$, denote by $A_n$ the event $\{\int_{0}^T \mathbf 1_{(-1/N, 1/N)} (a(s, X^n_s))ds > h\}$.

By the ucp convergence of $X^n$ to $X$, and the uniform continuity of $a$, we may choose $N_0$ large enough such that for each $n > N_0$, $|a(s, X^n_s) - a(s, X_s)| < \frac{1}{2N}$ on an event $B_n$ with $\mathbb P(B_n) >1 - r$.

Thus on $A^c_n \cap B_n$ we have that for all $s$ in a (random) set $H(n, \omega)$ of measure greater than $T - h$, either both $a(s, X^n_s)$ and $a(s, X_s)$ are less than $\frac{1}{2N}$, or both are greater than $\frac{1}{2N}$. We conclude that $\mathbb P \big(\big \{\mu\left(\left \{s \in [0, T]| \ f\left(a(s, X^n_s)\right) \neq f\left(a(s, X^n_s)\right) \right \}\right) > h\big \} \big) < 2r$.

Thus we estimate for all $n > \max(N, N_0)$,

$\mathbb E \big [\left (\int_{[0, T]} f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t\right)^2\big ]$

$=\mathbb E \big [\int_{[0, T]}\big( f\left(a(t,X^n_t)\right) - f \left(a(t,X_t)\right)\big)^2dt \big ]$

$=\mathbb E \big [ \mathbf 1_{A^c_n \cap B_n}  \int_{[0, T]}\big( f\left(a(t,X^n_t)\right) - f \left(a(t,X_t)\right)\big)^2dt \big ]+  \mathbb E \big [ \mathbf 1_{(A^c_n \cap B_n)^c} \int_{[0, T]}\big( f\left(a(t,X^n_t)\right) - f \left(a(t,X_t)\right)\big)^2dt \big]$

The first term is $0$ on $H(n, \omega)$ as stated earlier, so we have

$… = \mathbb E \big [ \mathbf 1_{A^c_n \cap B_n}  \int_{[0, T] \setminus H(n, \omega)}\big( f\left(a(t,X^n_t)\right) - f \left(a(t,X_t)\right)\big)^2dt \big ] + \mathbb E \big [ \mathbf 1_{(A^c_n \cap B_n)^c} \int_{[0, T]}\big( f\left(a(t,X^n_t)\right) - f \left(a(t,X_t)\right)\big)^2dt \big]$

$ \leq \mathbb E \big [ \mathbf 1_{A^c_n \cap B_n}  \int_{[0, T] \setminus H(n, \omega)}\frac{1}{4} dt \big ] + \mathbb E \big[ \mathbf 1_{(A^c_n \cap B_n)^c} \int_{[0, T]} \frac{1}{4} dt \big]$

$= \frac{h}{4} + \frac{rT}{2}.$

Thus by the Markov inequality we have

$\mathbb P \big (\left (\int_{[0, T]} f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t\right)^2 > \delta^2 \big) < (\frac{1}{\delta^2}) (\frac{h}{4} + \frac{rT}{2})$.

Setting now $h = 2\varepsilon \delta^2$ and $ r = \frac{\varepsilon \delta^2}{T}$, we have

$\mathbb P \big (\left (\int_{[0, T]} f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t\right)^2 > \delta^2 \big) < \varepsilon$

so that $\mathbb P \big (\left (\int_{[0, T]} f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X_t)\big)dW_t\right)^2 > \delta \big) < \varepsilon$

as required.

**Conclusion:**

Thus $X$ satisfies the SDE, and so we have strong existence as claimed.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I have been charged since yesterday and will read your solutions asap

Comment: I have read your reasoning, while I still do not see why the third and fourth terms (in your last e.q.) may converge to zero. For the third term, I can imagine but I need more details to make it rigorous. For the fourth term, I do not understand why the convergence may hold as $f$ is not continuous

Comment: In Lemma 1, I suppose you are talking about the SDE $dX_t=\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$, not $dY_t=\sigma(t,X_t)dW_t$

Comment: What is $\mu((a^{-1}((0, \frac{1}{N_{\delta}}))) \cap ([0, T] \times [-K, K])) < \delta$? Or more precisely, what is $a^{-1}((0, \frac{1}{N_{\delta}})))
$? I don't think it is well defined

Comment: Thanks for your reply - regarding your last two questions, yes Lemma 1 should be as you say. $a^{-1} (0, \frac{1}{N_\delta})$ is the subset $S$ of elements $(t, s)$ of $\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R$ such that $a(t, s) \in (0, \frac{1}{N_\delta})$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Regarding your first question, it is understandable that you need more details - I will add that on sometime today. You’re right about the problem with the fourth term though - I will have to think more on how to make that work.

Comment: I have added the details for the third term. I believe I can make the fourth term work as well, but for now I need a break haha!

Comment: By the way, may I ask what the motivation for this SDE is? It may help with my attempt to prove uniqueness later.

Comment: Of course. This SDE comes from a HJB type stochastic control problem, where $f$ represents the optimizer, i.e. if the state variable is positive, it invests all the wealth; otherwise it does not invest anything

Comment: Ah, very interesting! I had in mind some kind of “two state control”, good to see my guess was pretty much right. I will fix up the fourth term later, I’m rather certain it can be done.

Comment: Many thanks for adding more details. There are still two arguments that are not convincing for me : 1. In Lemma 1, $\delta_{\varepsilon, h}$ should depend on $\sigma$ (of the SDE). Therefore, the choice of $\delta$ in the proof below, should depend on $f_n(a(t,X^n_t))$ and thus on $n$, i.e. $\delta=\delta_n$. An argument is needed to show that $\delta$ can be chosen uniformly in $n$

Comment: 2. I don't think $\mathbb E \left[\mathbf 1_{A_n^c} \left(\int_{[0, T]} f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)dW_t\right)^2\right]= \mathbb E \left[ \left(\int_{[0, T]} \mathbf 1_{A_n^c}\left(f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - f \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right)dW_t\right)^2\right]= \mathbb E \left[\mathbf 1_{A_n^c}  \int_{[0, T]} \left[f_n\big(a(t,X^n_t)\big) - \big(a(t,X^n_t)\big)\right]^2 dt\right]$ may hold, as the indicator function $\mathbf 1_{A_n^c}$ is not $\mathcal F_t-$measurable to apply Ito's isometry

Comment: Ah, of course you are right. I do not immediately see how to fix these issues, but I will leave the answer up for now and try to work on it a little more soon.

Comment: So at least the second one seems easily fixable, which I have done. I will try to make an argument for the uniformness of $\delta_{\varepsilon, h}$ soon - this will require me to prove the lemma in full, most likely, so this will take quite awhile. In the meanwhile if you see any fixes, or if you find other things that need fixing, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I will also read the proof of the lemma, and my feeling is that the constant only depends on $C_1$ and $C_2$ (which is adapted to our case with $C_1=1/2$ and $C_2=1$). The main difficulty for me is the fourth term whose convergence to zero is not trivial for me as $f$ is not continuous

Comment: When editing a post that many times, please provide at least meaningful edit summaries (i.e. not just "added xyz characters in body"). -- Please remember -- each edit bumps the thread to the top of the front page.

Comment: @Stefal Kohl - Noted, thanks!

Comment: @Neymar I believe the fourth term can be dealt with in a similar way to the third - we argue that with high probability $a(s, X^n_s)$ spends very little time near $0$, and away from $0$ since $X_n$ will be close to $X$ with high probability, and $a$ is continuous, so too will $a(s, X_s)$. And in fact $f$ will be equal at those times. The main difficulty to me seems to be that it is not as easy to generalise the lemma. I should be able to prove the convergence of the fourth term by tomorrow. Maybe you could try to work on a rigorous proof of Lemma 1, with the uniform dependence included.

Comment: I have added in the details for the fourth term.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I still think there is something missing for the fourth term. Here you use the fact that $\mathbb P(\int_0^T{\bf 1}_{(-1/N,1/N)}(a(s,X^n_s))ds>h)\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$. Indeed, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\mathbb P(\int_0^T{\bf 1}_{(0,1/N)}(a(s,X^n_s))ds>h)\to 0$ is true, while the previous one may not be. For example, $\mathbb P(\int_0^T{\bf 1}_{\{a(s,X^n_s)=0\}}ds>h)>0$

Comment: For me, the essential difficulty to show the convergence of the fourth term is that the (random) Lebesgue measure $\mu(\{s: a(s,X^n_s)=0\})$ is "strictly larger" than zero

Comment: Ah, again you are right. I apologise for the mistake. This is a tricky problem indeed. I will give it a rest for now and attempt some other time, maybe more ideas will come.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your time and patience to think about my problem. Actually, I have another idea: Knowing that $dX^n_t=b^n_tdt+f^n_tdW_t$ converges ucp to $dX_t=b_tdt+f_tdW_t$, where $b^n, b$ and $f^n, f$ stand for the corresponding drift and volatility, I believe that we may expect "some kind of convergence" of $b^n$ to $b$ and $f^n$ to $f$ as $X^n$ and $X$ are both continuous semi-martingales. I guess we should make use of the "convergence" of $f^n$ to $f$

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you but I was wondering if you managed to make any progress on this problem.